Do I need to publish my youtube_analytics_api app for VERIFICATION in GCP to get access to monetary information for my YT channel?
I am trying to use the Youtube Analytics API to get monthly analytics regarding my channel performance. According to this url, it lists a variety of Metrics I have access to including things like estimatedMinutesWatched, views, likes, subscribersGained, estimatedRevenue, and etc. When I make the api call specifying these metrics estimatedMinutesWatched, views, likes, subscribersGained  I get a valid response and I can see the metrics breakdown based on the day. However when I add the metric estimatedRevenue, it gets me the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ayubs\OneDrive\Desktop\youtube-analytics\youtube_analytics_api_monthly_stats.py", line 104, in <module>
    execute_api_request(
  File "C:\Users\ayubs\OneDrive\Desktop\youtube-analytics\youtube_analytics_api_monthly_stats.py", line 92, in execute_api_request
    response = client_library_function(
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 840, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&startDate=2022-01-30&endDate=2022-02-15&metrics=estimatedMinutesWatched%2Cviews%2Clikes%2CsubscribersGained%2CestimatedRevenue&dimensions=day&sort=day&alt=json returned "Forbidden">

Here is how I am making the call, I downloaded my OAuth 2.0 Client IDs credentials which is stored in a json from GCP. I am importing those in my code which upon execution asks me to login to my email/youtube account.
I have pasted a copy of the code below:

import os
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

SCOPES = [  
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner'
        ]

API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtubeAnalytics'
API_VERSION = 'v2'
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
def get_service():
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
  credentials = flow.run_console()
  return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def execute_api_request(client_library_function, **kwargs):
  response = client_library_function(
    **kwargs
  ).execute()

  print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPs verification when running locally.
  # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled when running in production.
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

  youtubeAnalytics = get_service()
  execute_api_request(
      youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
      ids='channel==MINE',
      startDate='2022-01-30',
      endDate='2022-02-15',
      metrics='estimatedMinutesWatched,views,likes,subscribersGained,estimatedRevenue',
      dimensions='day',
      sort='day'
  )

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way? I just want to be able to pull monetary information regarding my channel whether that is related to ads or just estimatedRevenue.
the scopes I am using are the following and I have added these scopes in GCP:
[  
  '/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
  '/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly',
  '/auth/youtube.readonly',
  '/auth/youtube',
  '/auth/youtubepartner'
]


I know some of the functionality may be deprecated however I tried my best to use up to date API's if you see anything amiss, please guide. Thanks.

Forbidden means that you don't have access to do what you are trying to do.  You may have sent an access token but to access that data the user who created it must have access to that data.
from comments

The user that created the credentials (i specifically added the aforementioned scopes in GCP)

Just because someone creates application credentials does not give they any access to data a user must consent to that access.

has access because when I execute the above code, it does authentication where I login to youtube/google with that user and it even says do you want google to allow this user to get access to monetary information. I grant it, but it still says forbidden. I am not sure why this is happening.

Again just because the user grants an application access to something doesn't mean that that user has access to that data.
Is that user the owner of the channel?

The user that created the credentials (i specifically added the aforementioned scopes in GCP) has access because when I execute the above code, it does authentication where I login to youtube/google with that user and it even says do you want google to allow this user to get access to monetary information. I grant it, but it still says forbidden. I am not sure why this is happening.

I added my response to the question it was to much to respond to in comments.  that and they are great questions and deserve to be part of the answer :)
